# What exactly will happen to user access tokens with offline_access once that permission is permanently deprecated?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, authentication, oauth, access-token

We currently have many users with offline_access user tokens which we use to manage pages on their behalf. I have read the [Removal of offline_access](https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal) guide and the majority of the changes are clear, however there is one unknown we'd like to clarify.

Following the permanent deprecation of offline_access, we will switch to using non-expiring page access_tokens. We have thoroughly tested the workflow for new users, and have found no problems with exchanging short-lived tokens for long-lived ones, and then retrieving non-expiring page access_tokens using long-lived user access_tokens.

My query relates to retrieving non-expiring page tokens using existing offline_access access_tokens. The last sentence of 'Scenario 5: Page Access Tokens' in the aforementioned guide indicates that you should be able to use either long-lived access_tokens or offline_access access_tokens to retrieve non-expiring page access tokens, however when we tested with the offline_access tokens, the page access_tokens returned had a 2 month expiry date.

As the guide also states in Scenario 2 that offline_access tokens will only have their expiration date truncated to 60 days when the permission is permanently deprecated, we are making the assumption that at that point all offline_access tokens will be converted to long-lived user tokens.

If this assumption is correct, we have no problem as we already know page access_tokens obtained using long-lived user tokens have no expiry. However, if this assumption is incorrect and offline_access tokens will simply be given an expiry date at the point of deprecation, we have a problem as it seems that page access tokens retrieved with offline_access tokens will expire.

Is somebody able to confirm this assumption?

tl;dr When the offline_access permission is deprecated, will existing offline_access access_tokens be converted into long-lived user access_tokens, or will they just be given an expiry date?

Answer (score 0):

http://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/

> Scenario 2: If you have been previously requesting offline_access - updated 4/30/2012
>
> Once the migration has been enabled, existing use access_tokens, with the offline_access permission, will continue to work without any change to their expiration time. However, new users to your app will not be prompted for the offline_access permission in the Auth Dialog and will receive either a short-lived or long-lived access_token depending on your environment and how you are requesting the access_token (client or server-side OAuth, see Scenario 3 and 4 below).
>
> After the offline_access removal date (see roadmap for exact date), all existing offline_access access_tokens will have their expiration time truncated to 60 days. This truncation will be transparent to the user and your app will continue functioning normally; Facebook will send an updated message through the weekly developer round-up when this truncation will occur.

Comment: Hi Hugo, thanks for the reply but that information does not answer my question. As I stated, I am trying to find out what is meant by "all existing offline_access access_tokens will have their expiration time truncated to 60 days". Can you confirm that the offline_access access_tokens will be unchanged except for the expiry date? Or do you think they could be converted to long-lived tokens?

Comment: 60 days token are the long-lived token for facebook because their normal tokens last 2 hours. So after they are removed, their expiration will be 60 days, and thus they will need to be renewed every 60 days.

Comment: I see your point, but as we can't use offline_access access_tokens to retrieve the non-expiring page tokens we need, I need to be sure that the offline_access tokens will be actually converted into long-lived tokens on Oct. 3rd, not just assume their behaviour (i.e. be given a 60 day expiry). Does that make sense? Please let me know if I can clarify further.

Comment: Well as right now that's all the infos facebook published. And by what is writen, what I can understand is that all the off_acc tokens will have a 60 day expiry from Oct. 3rd. Maybe they will publish new infos but from Facebook. If I were you I would send them a message to be sure.

Comment: Sure ok thanks Hugo, would you happen to know where I can send a message to Facebook? On their contact page they simply direct you to this stack overflow.

Comment: From what is said on Facebook is that their developpers are often on facebook.stackoverflow.com but they do not provide any email or support else than this